# Conexión a base de datos remota desde api .net core

Tags: sql-server, .net, asp.net-core

Tengo un problema al conectar una api desarrollada en .net core 2.2. Cuando quiero consultar a una base de datos local o ejecutar un update-database desde la consola Nuget funciona todo bien, pero el problema esta cuando conecto con una base de datos remota, cambie la cadena de conexión la cual incluye usuario y password.

Recalco que conectándome directamente desde SqlServer o desde Visual Studio funciona (o sea el servidor esta funcionando), pero al ejecutar la api web no.

El servidor ya esta configurado para usar conexiones remotas y el puerto 1433 esta habilitado

Que podría ser?

Gracias, saludos.

Comment: y cual es el error que muestra?

Comment: Que no se puede conectar con la instancia especifica o no la encuentra, como si fuera que tengo mal configurada la cadena de conexion, pero me fije varias veces y esta bien

Comment: Este es el error que tira : A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: ¿Cual es tu cadena de conexion? ¿Cual es el nombre de tu servidor o instancia?

Comment: Hola. La cadena de conexion es la siguiente: "Data Source=ipServer\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=*******;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=******" lo peor de todo es el servidor ya esta trabajando con otros proyectos remotamente, pero con .net core no, en los otrs proyectos simplemente cambian la cadena de conexion y listo, funciona. Ya no se que mas hacer